# Kendo ui grid server-side pagination not working?

Tags: kendo-ui, pagination, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-grid

I'm trying to implement server-side pagination with kendo-ui grid. This is my datasource configuration.

```
"dataSource": {
            "serverPaging": true,
            "pageSize": 10,
            "schema":{
              "data": "data",
              "total": "total"
            },
            "transport": {
              "read": {
                "url": "http://localhost:9001/category/widget/kendoGridTest/trigger/data",
                "dataType": "json",
                "type": "GET"
              }
            }
 }
```

When I run it, it continuously sending server requests but nothing happening. The sending requests are correct and getting the expected response too. No data-binding on the grid happening.

Anyone has idea what has gone wrong here??

**Edit: Server Response**

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "CustomerID": "ALFKI",
            "CompanyName": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
            "ContactName": "Maria Anders",
            "ContactTitle": "Sales Representative",
            "Address": "Obere Str. 57",
            "City": "Berlin"
        },
        {
            "CustomerID": "YUI",
            "CompanyName": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
            "ContactName": "Maria Anders",
            "ContactTitle": "Sales Representative",
            "Address": "Obere Str. 57",
            "City": "Berlin"
        },
        {
            "CustomerID": "PKY",
            "CompanyName": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
            "ContactName": "Maria Anders",
            "ContactTitle": "Sales Representative",
            "Address": "Obere Str. 57",
            "City": "Berlin"
        },
        {
            "CustomerID": "PNY",
            "CompanyName": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
            "ContactName": "Maria Anders",
            "ContactTitle": "Sales Representative",
            "Address": "Obere Str. 57",
            "City": "Berlin"
        },
        {
            "CustomerID": "WSI",
            "CompanyName": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
            "ContactName": "Maria Anders",
            "ContactTitle": "Sales Representative",
            "Address": "Obere Str. 57",
            "City": "Berlin"
        },
        {
            "CustomerID": "FGH",
            "CompanyName": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
            "ContactName": "Maria Anders",
            "ContactTitle": "Sales Representative",
            "Address": "Obere Str. 57",
            "City": "Berlin"
        },
        {
            "CustomerID": "NMV",
            "CompanyName": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
            "ContactName": "Maria Anders",
            "ContactTitle": "Sales Representative",
            "Address": "Obere Str. 57",
            "City": "Berlin"
        }
    ],
    "total": 7
}
```

Comment: Show the server response, please.

Comment: @dimodi hi.. I have added to the question. :))

Comment: OK, so this DataSource configuration and this sample response work as expected on my side: http://dojo.telerik.com/AgAkE Check the data response MIME type and verify there are no JavaScript errors.

Comment: @dimodi I'm getting 'uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null ' this console error per every request going. (I'm using TypeScript). For a moment I thought it has no connection here. Any idea??